# How to capture cascading 302 redirects in IE8 BHO?

Tags: c++, com, internet-explorer-8, bho

I am currently finishing up a C++ BHO project for my company, and I discovered a pretty critical bug a lot later in the process than I had hoped. I have a BHO that currently uses SINK to capture BeforeNavigate2, NavigateComplete2, NavigateError, and several other events, but I am running into an issue capturing 302 redirect URLs.

So for example, lets say we have 4 sites:

a starting site A that has a link to B
a site B that 302 redirects to site C
a site C that 302 redirects to site D,
a final site D

The user starts on site A: clicks site B: site B redirects to site C, site C redirects to site D: user winds up at site D.

In this scenario, my BeforeNavigate2 will capture site B's URL, and my NavigateComplete will capture site D's URL. But site C is completely invisible to my BHO. You could add any number of 302s in-between B and D in this scenario and I'm not able to capture any of them.

Note: I solved this in Internet Explorer 7 by adding a DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION to the GetHostInfo flag, which made every redirect trigger a BeforeNavigate2. But it appears IE8 does not respect this flag :(

Comment: FWIW, DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION should still work fine; you may want to contact Microsoft Developer support.

Comment: I thought so too, but I can confirm my other MSHTML overwrites in GetHostInfo work fine. I tried including DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO and scrollbars were gone so I know some of the flags work. My coworker is talking to Microsoft Developer support right now, hopefully they will have an answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deep into HTTP using IHttpNegotiate. But it same as injecting a HTTP sniffer into your application.

Comment: To sum this one up, we contacted Microsoft Developer support and this turns out to be a bug in IE8. This bug does not exist in IE7 or IE9, and the developer was able to narrow it down to a return call that exited the redirect too early to trigger the doc host. So my company wound up using IHttpNegotiate, and everything works great.